# Analise com R do Censo Demografico

Tags: r

Preciso ler os dados do Censo demográfico do IBGE, da base de pessoas, no caso do código abaixo eu baixei os dados da UF desejada manualmente, consegui lê-los no R, mas na hora da analise não entendi muito bem como criar o plano amostral com o pacote survey, alguem consegue me ajudar?

```
ww <- fwf_positions(
  c(3,8,21,29, 154, 158),
  c(7,20,28,44, 155, 158),
  c('mun','areap','contr','peso', 'curso', 'instr'))

colcl <- do.call('cols', list('i','d','d', 'd', 'i', 'i'))

r <- read_fwf('Amostra_Pessoas_27.txt', ww,colcl)
```

Sei que preciso criar algo como essa variavel:

`amostra <- svydesign(ids = ~ contr, strata = ~ areap, weights = ~ peso, fpc = ~ FPC, data = r)`

mas não sei como criar a variável FPC para isso, e após a criação dessa variável é só usar o pacote survey normalmente? como:

`df<-svyby(~curso,~instr,amostra,na.rm=T)`

ou precisaria de uma passo a mais?